# Build fails with latest React Native (AdMob)

Tags: android, react-native

```
    `enter code here`G:\workspace_android\qb_current_affairs\node_modules\react-native-admob\android\src\main\java\com\sbugert\rnadmob\RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.java:20: 
error: RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRewardedVideoCompleted() in RewardedVideoAdListener

public class RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
           ^
    1 error
```

Use following  react and plugin version

```
"react": "16.6.1",
"react-native": "0.57.5",
 "react-native-admob": "^1.3.2",
```

admob react package url : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue with the library (https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/316), upgrade to version 2 using:

```
yarn add react-native-admob@next
```

or

```
npm install react-native-admob@next
```

if you are using npm